# jon raasch slideshow - two on one site

Tags: jquery, slideshow

Simple jQuery slideshow by Jon Raasch. I use this on my home page. I want to use a second slideshow on a subordinate page but the second slideshow defaults to using the first show's active image, even though I have reset the source on the subordinate page, as below

```
<img id="start" src="slideshow/spectators.jpg" alt="" class="active" />
```

The line below in the slideshow does not seem to pick up the new image.

```
var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');
```

Any help appreciated.

Bob

Comment: Can you show some more of your html? I am interested specifically to see at what point you are calling your javascript, and the contextual code.